# Unable to implement third-party Google Calendar Conferencing Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, conferencing

I'm working on the Google Calendar conferencing add-ons implementation and found some problems. I follow the documentation to execute the sample code, but it does not work as expected.

From my point of view, my manifest file is complete, but when I try to publish the Calendar conferencing add-on from the 'Deploy from manifest' link, it opens my google calendar, but it does not show my conferencing as it shows the Hangout and Uberconference for example.

I was expecting some log messages on my entry point function in Stackdriver, but even that is not working. 
Do you have any clues where I should start my investigation?
Below is my manifest file and also my createConference function definition.

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
        "userSymbol": "Calendar",
        "serviceId": "calendar",
        "version": "v3"
    }],
    "libraries": [{
        "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
        "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsiaserTMogajsHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
        "version": "21"
    }]
},
"webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
},
"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
],
"urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://circuitsandbox.net/"
],
"calendar": {
    "name": "My Web Conferencing",
    "logoUrl": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sgkt743sv30rid1/logo-circuit-100x100.png?dl=0",
    "createSettingsUrlFunction": "createSettingsUrl",
    "conferenceSolution": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "My Web Conference",
            "logoUrl": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sgkt743sv30rid1/logo-circuit-100x100.png?dl=0",
            "onCreateFunction": "createConference"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "My Recorded Web Conference",
            "logoUrl": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sgkt743sv30rid1/logo-circuit-100x100.png?dl=0",
            "onCreateFunction": "createConference"
        }
    ]
}


function createConference(arg) {
var dataBuilder = ConferenceDataService.newConferenceDataBuilder();
var authenticationUrl = 'https://adfs01.circuitsandbox.net/';
    var error = ConferenceDataService.newConferenceError()
        .setConferenceErrorType(
            ConferenceDataService.ConferenceErrorType.AUTHENTICATION)
        .setAuthenticationUrl(authenticationUrl);
    dataBuilder.setError(error);
return dataBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the samples / documentation to implement a Google Calendar conferencing add-on? I can't find any info regarding `ConferenceDataService`

Comment: @Gustavo Valensuela Were you able to get it to work? And also would you mind sharing how you got on the whitelist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be whitelisted to develop and debug google calendar plugins by Google.

Edit: At that point in time, you needed to have a contact within google that whitelisted you, not sure if this is still the case. Did not work on this for a long time. Not sure how to get in contact with them, I never was in any direct contact myself.

Comment: I'm on the whitelist so I can see all the documentation, but for some reason, I can not make the example to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: How to get whitelisted? Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: How to get whitelisted? I saw Zoom/Webex/BlueJeans/SalesForce/UberConference and several AddOns on the G Suite marketplace. How to be like them ?

Comment: At that point in time, you needed to have a contact within google that whitelisted you. Not sure how to get in contact with them, I never was in any direct contact.