# Third-party conferencing in Google Calendar from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to add third-party conferencing via Google Apps Script yet?

I'm referring to the functionality mentioned here: https://www.blog.google/products/g-suite/bring-teams-together-new-g-suite-integrations/

If not, is there any way to get access to it e.g. getting whitelisted?

Comment: There appears to be some mentioned of it in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), look for `conferenceData`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I have looked at it already, but sadly, it is not it, unless I am missing something. I would like to add third-party conferencing with custom UI etc. conferenceData allows only allows me to set eventHangout and another hangouts variant.

This add-on does something similar to what i want to achieve: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/cisco_webex/678783785621.

It (the integration) was also shown in the link in my original question.

Comment: I see, I did see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDBEiiCY8qU), but it seems to be only UI-based, and you're trying to find a GAS way to approach it, correct?

Comment: It does not have to necessarily be Google Apps Script, but as far as I know, that is where you can use the API for adding conferences. I have also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887856/unable-to-implement-third-party-google-calendar-conferencing-add-on), and there it looks like you need to be whitelisted.

Comment: After checking the documentation further, I took the liberty of creating a feature request for Google to look into this, you can check for updates [following this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/140221056).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! 
I see you mentioned, and I suppose those are [Apps Script add-ons], but I have not been successful in finding any documentation there either.

Comment: That's why I created the FR, could not find any relevant documentation other than the article you had shared, we'll see what they say in the tracker.

Comment: Currently it is possible, more info here (official doc): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/create-conference

Answer (score 0):

Posting for documentation.

After going over the [event documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) there does not seem to be a way to programmatically work with third-party conferencing. I created a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/140221056), this link will serve to keep track of updates on this issue.